# Setting a selectbox value from spring mvc

Tags: java, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

How to set a selectbox value in jsp from controller.

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
```

I created new object for entity **Employee** and then set the value of 
designation with this code..

```
employee.setEmpDesignation(addEmployeeForm.getEmpDesignation());
```

Here is the jsp

```
<form:select path="empDesignation" id="emplDesignation" onchange="showTextBox();" cssClass="textBox">
    <c:forEach var="desig" items="${designation}">
        <option value="${desig.designationDesc}">
              <c:out value="${desig.designationDesc}"/>
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

Basically I am trying to set the values entered by the user,when error occurs.

But it always displays the first value in the selectbox.

Comment: In Spring MVC, form tags – <form:select />, <form:option /> or <form:options />, are used to render HTML dropdown box. Check tis to know more http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not using `<form:options>` ?

E.g:

```
<form:select path="empDesignation">
    <form:options items="${designation}" itemLabel="designationDesc" itemValue="designationDesc"/>
</form:select>
```

if your form backing object is bound, SpringMVC should handle all this for you.

Comment: You're welcome.  I've just recently gone through the pain of learning SpringMVC myself, so I can sympathise! :-)