# Select box with a selected item

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu

Let's say I have a list of countries populated in a select box something like the following.

```
<form:select path="country">
    <form:option value="-" label="--Please Select"/>
    <form:options items="${countryList}" itemValue="countryId" itemLabel="countryName"/>
</form:select>
```

Where `countryList` in EL of the `items` attribute is a `List<Country>` - `Country` refers to a Hibernate entity.

I need to select an appropriate country based on the `countryId` supplied so that the generated HTML should roughly be shown as follows.

```
<select name="country">
    <option value="">--Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Austria</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="3">United States</option>
</select>
```

In this case, UK is the selected country. Is it possible without using the `<c:foreach>` loop of JSTL?

I'm using Spring 3.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to declare a variable `country`  in action class.Then put setter and getters and then set your value in action class.But the select box path name and and variable name must be same.

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616065/setting-a-selectbox-value-from-spring-mvc)  for example