# jsp how to set the selected value?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to set the selected value of a select element from server side, but not getting idea how can I set the value, here is my code.
java code

```
model.addAttribute("dataSources", dataSourceRepository.findByDestinationId(sDestination.getId()));
```

jsp code:

```
<form:select onchange="refreshHistoryPage()" path="id" items="${dataSources}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>
```

Comment: Are you using any framework ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting a selectbox value from spring mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616065/setting-a-selectbox-value-from-spring-mvc)